# Solving $\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\beta x}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\ln(s_0)-(\mu-\sigma^2/2)}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}\right)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

while trying to price an option with the Black scholes model, I came across this integral:$$\frac{e^{-rT}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma \sqrt{T}}\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\beta x}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\ln(s_0)-(\mu-\sigma^2/2)}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}\right)^2}\, \mathrm{d}x$$

Sadly, can't solve it. The solution has to be something in terms $\Phi(\cdot)$ (cdf of the normal dist.) Can someone help me? The first step will probably to use $e^{x}e^{y}=e^{x+y}$.

**More context**

We have $S_T\sim \operatorname{LogNormal}(\ln(s_0)+(\mu-\sigma^2/2),\sigma^2T)$, i.e. $\ln(S_T)\sim \mathcal{N}(\ln(s_0)+(\mu-\sigma^2/2),\sigma^2T)$.

I'm trying to compute $e^{-rT}E((S_T)^{\beta})=e^{-rT}E(e^{\ln(S_T)\beta})$. So I used LOTUS on $e^{-rT}E(g(S_T))$ with $g(x)=e^{\beta x}$.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+from+-infty+to+infty+e%5E%28ax%29+e%5E%28-1%2F2%28%28x-b%29%2Fc%29%5E2%29

Comment: Did that too. There are no steps though. At least in the free version.

Comment: Add powers, complete the square, apply linear substitution to get erf multiplied by some constant.

Comment: @Vasili Could you elaborate?

Comment: In the solution you accepted, there is a mistake in the final solution: $d = \ln(s_0)-(\mu-\sigma^2/2)$ needs to be $d = \ln(s_0)\color{red}{+}(\mu-\sigma^2/2)$. Moreover, $c$ is defined as $c=\sigma T$, which should be $c=\sigma\color{red}{\sqrt{T}}$. You may use it carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral is realted to **the moment generating function** of the normal distribution ([mgf](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/533352/399354)).

$$\frac{e^{-rT}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma \sqrt{T}}\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\beta x}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\ln(s_0)-(\mu-\sigma^2/2)}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}\right)^2}  \mathrm{d}x=e^{-rT} \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\beta x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\color{green}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}}e^{\frac{\left (x-\color{blue}{(\ln(s_0)+(\mu-\sigma^2/2))}\right)^2}{-2(\color{green}{\sigma \sqrt{T}})^2}}  \mathrm{d}x=e^{-rT} M_X(\beta)=e^{-rT} e^{ 
 \beta \left (\ln(s_0)+(\mu-\sigma^2/2) \right ) +\frac{1}{2} \beta^2 (\sigma \sqrt{T})^2}\\ = \exp \left ( -rT+ \beta(\ln(s_0)+\mu-\sigma^2/2) +\frac{1}{2} \beta^2 \sigma^2 T\right )$$

where $$X\sim N \left ( \underbrace{ \color{blue}{\ln(s_0)+\mu-\sigma^2/2}}_{\mu_X}, \underbrace{ \left( \color{green}{\sigma \sqrt{T}} \right)^2}_{\sigma^2_X} \right)$$ and

$$M_X(\beta)=\mathbb E \left(\text{e}^{\beta X} \right)=\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\beta x}f_X(x) \mathrm{d}x=e^{\beta \mu_X +\frac{1}{2} \beta^2 \sigma_X^2} $$

denotes the mgf of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $
2c^2\beta x - (x-d)^2 = -x^2 + 2x(d+\beta c^2) + d^2 = -(x-m)^2 - d^2 + m^2
$,
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi c^2}}\int_R e^{\beta x-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-d}{c})^2}dx
=e^{\frac{m^2 - d^2}{2c^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi c^2}}\int_R e^{\frac{-1}{2c^2}(x -m)^2}dx = e^{\frac{m^2 - d^2}{2c^2}} = e^{\frac{\beta^2c^2 + 2 \beta d}{2}}.
$$
Thus, $
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2 T}} \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\beta x}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\ln(s_0)-(\mu-\sigma^2/2)}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}\right)^2}dx=e^{\frac{\beta^2c^2 + 2 \beta d}{2}}.
$
With $c=\sigma T$ and $d = \ln(s_0)-(\mu-\sigma^2/2)$
the integral equals
$
e^{\frac{1}{2}(\beta \sigma \sqrt{T})^2 + \beta\big(\ln(s_0)-(\mu-\sigma^2/2)\big)}.
$